# How to get the latitude and longitude from address that users input in the text box

Tags: android, geolocation, geocoding, google-geocoder, geofire

I need a little help with my code. I'm trying to get the users address that they input from the edittext and get that address lattitutde and longitude and save that in geofire. I'm able to get the current users longitude and latitude and save it to geofire but what if the user wanted to use a different address and I get the latitude and longitude for that specific address instead and save it in  geofire how would I go about that? I hope you my question is'nt confusing to you all. Below is my code Thanks in advance.

```
 FusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(final Location location) {
                    if (location != null) {
                        Double latittude = location.getLatitude();
                        Double longitude = location.getLongitude();





                        String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child("address");
                        DatabaseReference update =  reference.child("Users").child(uid);

                        GeoFire geoFire=new GeoFire( reference);





                        geoFire.setLocation(uid, new GeoLocation(latittude, longitude), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {
                                if (error != null) {
                                    System.err.println("There was an error saving your location to GeoFire: " + error);
                                } else {
                                    System.out.println("Location saved on the server successfully!");
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

u have to use places API from google to achieve

following below links may help u

https://github.com/googlearchive/android-play-places/blob/master/PlaceCompleteAdapter/Application/src/main/java/com/example/google/playservices/placecomplete/PlaceAutocompleteAdapter.java

https://medium.com/skillhive/android-google-places-autocomplete-feature-bb3064308f05

Comment: Thanks for responding. I will take a look at it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use simple Reverse Geocoding

```
 Location location = appLocationService
                    .getLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);



              if (location != null) {
                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                LocationAddress locationAddress = new LocationAddress();
                locationAddress.getAddressFromLocation(latitude, longitude,
                        getApplicationContext(), new GeocoderHandler());
            } else {
                showSettingsAlert();
            }
```

Look at this for more information:
https://javapapers.com/android/android-get-address-with-street-name-city-for-location-with-geocoding/

Answer (score 0):

Try It

```
Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
List<Address> address;
double lat, lang;

try {
    address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress,5);
    if (address==null) {
       return null;
    }
    Address location=address.get(0);
    lat = location.getLatitude();
    lang = location.getLongitude();
}
```